# How to use output of one query into another query in python/ sql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have one query which is like:

```
        q = f"""
                select distinct
                    s.user_id
                    ,d.prime_tagging_by_issuer_and_product
                from sms_callback_events s
                    inner join {table} d
                    on s.user_id = d.user_id
                    where event_name = 'event_1'
                    and d.user_id is not null and d.user_id != ''
            """
        with redshift_direct() as conn:
            sms_df = pd.read_sql(q, conn)
```

Now I want to discard only those user_ids which were selected in this query and pass rest of the user Id's to my another query which is also similar

```
 q = f"""
                    select distinct
                        s.user_id
                        ,d.prime_tagging_by_issuer_and_product
                    from flash_events s
                        inner join {table} d
                        on s.user_id = d.user_id
                        where event_name = 'event_1'
                        and d.user_id is not null and d.user_id != ''
                """
            with redshift_direct() as conn:
                flash_df = pd.read_sql(q, conn)
```

here `{table}` is nothing but a dataframe of user_ids and plus some other columns.

How do I achieve this? How do I put a condition where I dont pass the user ids from `sms_df` to my next query?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not putting the first query as a sub-query in the second one? And have 1 query with `WHERE user_id not in (<first_query>)`

Comment: there is too much data to pull from the server, i have optimised the code in that way.